# How to create a table from current unordered list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to parse a multi-level unordered list to table.

I have got the current code like

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#home">Homepage</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#1">Main Item 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#11">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#12">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#13">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#14">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#2">Main Item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#21">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#22">Sub Item 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#23">Sub Item 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#3">Main Item 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#31">Sub Item 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#32">Sub Item 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want the list to turn into a table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Main Item 1</th><th>Main Item 2</th><th>Main Item 3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr><td>Sub Item 1.1</td><td>Sub Item 2.1</td><td>Sub Item 3.1</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Sub Item 1.2</td><td>Sub Item 2.2</td><td>Sub Item 3.2</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Sub Item 1.3</td><td>Sub Item 2.3</td><td> </td></tr>
       <tr><td>Sub Item 1.4</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In order to get that table, I have tried to get all `li` elements into an array 'menuElements'. Then I have tried to add table header cells first in a for loop.

```
var menuElements = [];
$("ul#menu_ li").each(function() { menuElements.push($(this))});
```

I am trying to create a table after getting all list items into array 'menuElements'. `menuElements[i].innerHtml` returns `undefined`.

So I am stuck here.

The next step is to add sub items to corresponding main item column.

```
$("#new_menu").html("<table class='table'><thead><tr>");    

//starting from 1 because I do not want to show Homepage link.
for (i = 1; i < menuElements.length; i++)
{
    //if current menu item has 'dropdown' class then it is a first level item and it should be on table header.
    if(menuElements[i].hasClass("dropdown") === true)
    {
        $("#new_menu").append("<th>" + menuElements[i].innerHtml + "<th>");
    }
}

//end table header and begin table body         
$("#footer_menu").append("</tr></thead><tbody>");   


for (i = 1; i < menuElements.length; i++)
{
    //if current menu item has 'dropdown' class then it is a first level item and it should be on table header.
    if(menuElements[i].hasClass("dropdown") === false)
    {
        $("#new_menu").append("<td>" + menuElements[i].innerHtml + "<td>");
    }
}       


//end table     
$("#footer_menu").append("</tbody></table>");
```

I am dead sure that there is a better and quicker way to do this as jQuery's slogan says: **Write less, do more**. Because this is painful.

Comment: May be a silly question but is there any reason why you don't just output a table instead of a list?

Comment: I agree with @dwhite.me change the output HTML first. Using JS as a crutch on the UI like this is not a good idea.

Comment: @dwhite.me it is not a silly question. List is populated from database which I do not have access and have to do it as in the question.

Comment: My question being silly, not yours. It's an expression... Anyway, is the list structure in the table cell contents?

Comment: your menu structure is wrong, you need to add a new ul before you close the preceding li (not in between li) - just noticed that was the first li only so may be a copy and paste error.  Also what would happen if there were a second sub level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help you get started:

```
var rowCount = 0,
    lis = $('#menu').children('li'),
    colCount = lis.length,
    table = '<table><thead><tr>';

lis.each(function(index) {
    //don't do homepage
    if (index > 0) {
        var li = $(this);
        table += '<th>' + li.children('a').text() + '</th>';

        var childRows = li.find('li').length;
        if (rowCount < childRows) {
            rowCount = childRows; 
        }
    }
});

table += '</tr></thead>';
table += '<tbody>';

for (r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
{
    table += '<tr>';

    // start column count at 1 because of homepage link
    for (c = 1; c < colCount; c++)
    {
        var text = lis.eq(c).find('ul a').eq(r).text();
        if (text == '') {
            text = '&nbsp;';
        }

        table += '<td>' + text + '</td>';
    }

    table += '</tr>';
}

table += '</tbody>';
table += '</table>';

$('body').append(table);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cdv96wbm/1/)

Comment: Added links to sub items. see: http://jsfiddle.net/pq3aoL0d/ . Now it is better. Thanks.

Comment: ah yeah, probably need to do that to the headings too!

Answer (score 0):

What about this...  if it comes out of the database as a string containing ul & li tags, I'd use middleware to modify the string as an html table before sending it to the front end.

Comment: You should really provide an example of the suggestion you just made, otherwise, this doesn't qualify as an acceptable answer to this question.